# What version of Silverlight does Visual Studio 2010 support right out-of-the-box?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, version

I am just starting out with Silverlight and found it a nightmare setting up the right environment;

I have VS2010 Pro (4.0.30319.1) installed, download some example from Ms code gallery, but was an earlier version so it asked me to covert the said example, which i did; So presumably this upgraded it to version SL4?

Anyway i still could not debug until i installed SL4 Developers Runtime; then debugging worked;

But on another example (this one http://wildermuth.com/downloads/riaxboxgames.zip
), it would not even load some projects in the solution... complaining about: "The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

So a side question is how to force VS to load a project, so that at least some of the source can be viewed - i accept it may not be compile-able, but viewable it should be without resorting to Notepad...

Anyway, 3 hours later after trial and error (and Googling) i find bits and pieces that lead me to install the SL4 Runtime, the SL4 Tools for VS2010, which again is different from the SL4 Toolkit on codeplex.

Then there's the SL SDK... Is there a redux somewhere that explains what all these different components / installations do for a SL beginner?

Comment: Sounds to me like you found the required bits and pieces.  Do you still have a problem?

Comment: No problem right now, the few samples that i downloaded can be loaded and built. But the next problem may be just around the corner when i download the next sample and find out that i missed out on SL4 Runtime for Astronauts or something like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

It comes with an out dated version of Silverlight. :)

Whenever you install Visual Studio just go to http://www.silverlight.net/getting-started and you will find instructions on what you need to install there. Soon it will change to Silverlight 5.